# this code works fine on ie 10 but not on chrome and firefox (javascript/ajax portion)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

this code works fine on IE10 but on chrome and firefox the slider is not displayed .....everything else works fine

zip link:   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5TtGpU9w1RVZWpsYzF6YWRmWWc/edit?usp=sharing

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Website template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome To India</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnRight', 
    speed:  'slow', 

    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' 
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="background">
    <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="" alt="LOGO" height="112" width="118"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li class="selected">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="about.php">Discover India</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="forum.php">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="tripplanner.php">Trip Planner</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="holidays.php">Holidays</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="news.php">Cuisines</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
    <div id="adbox">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
    <div id="slider">
    <img src="Best-Heavy-Bike-Image-960x720.jpeg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="bike">
    <img src="Jumping-Cute-Dophin-Image-960x720.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="dolphin">
    <img src="Nikon-D800-Skeleton-Image.jpeg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="nikon">
    </div>
    <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Enjoy the holidays in India</h1>
    <p>
    <a href="index.php">Welcome To India</a> About India <a href="forum.php">Forum</a>.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    <div class="box">
    <div>
    <div>
    <h3>Latest Blog</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <h4><a href="news.php">Popular Monuments</a></h4>
    <p>
    all popular monuments listed here
    </p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <h4><a href="news.php">Popular Tourists Spots</a></h4>
    <span>May 29, 2023</span>
    <p>
    all popular tourist places are listed here
    </p>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="testimonials" class="box">
    <div>
    <div>
    <h3>History</h3>
    <p>
    History of india <span>- <a href="index.php">Welcome To India</a></span>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="section">
    <a href="rooms.jpg"><img src="images/rooms.jpg" alt="Img"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
    <a href="tripplanner.php"><img src="images/dive-site.jpg" alt="Img"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
    <a href="holidays.php"><img src="images/food.jpg" alt="Img"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <div>
    <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="about.php">Discover India</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="forum.php">Forum </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="tripplanner.php">Trip Planner</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="holidays.php">Holidays</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="news.php">Cuisines</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="connect">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a> <a href="http://www.googleplus.com/" target="_blank" class="googleplus"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>
    © 2013 by Roy
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Two words: DOM ready.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That was my first thought too, but why would it work in IE10?

Comment: @Archer: probably because IE was so slow to run the javascript/jquery, the dom/element was actually ready. Just a guess

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I like that because I can take it as either an answer or a joke :D

Comment: @Archer [This page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) suggests that IE10 intentionally delays script execution until the DOM has finished loading: "However, even in non-buggy implementations, such as IE10 and other browsers, script execution is delayed until the whole document has downloaded and parsed." I have no idea if that's actually true, but it sounds sort of plausible, and it's the only/most obvious issue with the code in non-IE browsers. Disclaimer: I only skimmed that page, so I may have misunderstood what it's intended to say.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's an interesting read.  Bookmarked for regular reference - Thanks :)

Comment: @Archer check my site abc.comyr.com .....the same problem is occuring again...it worked fine 2 days before when i implemented this code(which is provided in the answer below).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist .........please read the comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap following code in `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').cycle({ 
        fx:     'turnRight', 
        speed:  'slow', 

        next:   '#next', 
        prev:   '#prev' 
    });
});
```

Comment: check my site abc.comyr.com .....the same problem is occuring again...it worked fine 2 days before when i implemented this code(which u provided in this answer).

Comment: @GauravRoy it's working fine in my Chrome 29, what exactly doesn't work here?